# How is memory allocated when passing inherited class as param to a method using this keyword?

Tags: .net

I am a junior developer and I am not sure if the sample code below is a good practice. I would like to know if there is a performance impact by passing current class instance as a parameter of a method.  Also what could be the performance impact by passing it to several methods? Please advise on the code below.

```
Class X: Y
{

  Z myObject = new Z();
   myObject.MethodA( (Y)this);
}


Class Z
{

   MethodA(Y y)
  {
     y.Mystream = Write Element
     MethodB(ref y)
     MethodC(ref y)

   }
   MethodB(ref Y y)
  {
     y.Mystream = Write Element

   }
 }


Class Y
{  
    Public XMLTextWriter  Mystream = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case (`MethodA(this)`), a copy of the reference is passed by value to the method. This is blazingly fast. I guarantee it's not a bottleneck in your application.

In the second case (`MethodB(ref y)`), the storage location of the reference is passed to the method. This is blazingly fast. I guarantee it's not a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Whaoo good to know. I didn't know that a copy of the reference is passed by value when this is passed asThank You

Comment: Now I think about it more.. I am not 100% clear on MethodA(this).. Class X has an instance and it inherits Y.  Does it copy the entire object on the heap or just the address? Also MethodB(ref Y) y is an xml stream I am creating passed to different methods. So there is no overhead by creating and closing the stream every time class x is instantiated?

Comment: @user596342 it is just the reference (which in real terms is the address, but some people get very upset if you claim the two are the same thing ;p). The object itself is not copied. Re opening and closing a stream - you'd need to be more specific on the scenario.

Comment: Cool. I am clear is just the address. Yeah I made no sense reg opening and closing the stream question. In other words.. what I wanted to know is that if there is a performance impact by passing a xml stream thru several methods by ref? The stream will be created and closed one time by class Y.